# Ошибка ABNORMAL_EXIT

Tags: python, алгоритм, python-3.12

популярной игре для оценки силы игрока используется система рейтинга. Она работает настолько хорошо, что результат матча в формате
1
×
1
(один игрок против одного игрока) можно предсказать для всех игроков с различным рейтингом. Игрок с большим рейтингом гарантированно выиграет матч.

Для матчей в формате
2
×
2
(команда из двух игроков против команды из двух игроков) эта система работает уже не так хорошо, но информация о рейтингах игроков все равно может быть полезна. Команда
A
гарантированно одержит победу только в том случае, когда любой из игроков команды
A
гарантированно одержит победу над любым игроком команды
B
. Во всех остальных случаях победа не гарантирована.

Вам заданы рейтинги всех игроков, участвующих в матче
2
×
2
. Сможете ли вы предсказать победителя?

Входные данные
В первой строке задается два числа
a
1
и
a
2
— рейтинги игроков команды
A
.

Во второй строке задается два числа
b
1
и
b
2
— рейтинги игроков команды
B
.

Все числа целые, положительные и не превосходят
100
.

Выходные данные
Если команда
A
гарантированно одержит победу, то выведите WIN.

Если команда
A
гарантированно проиграет, то выведите LOSE. В этом случае команда
B
гарантированно выиграет.

Если точно предсказать результат матча невозможно, то выведите UNKNOWN.

я сделал код для этой задачи, но система выдает ошибку ABNORMAL_EXIT

вот код

```
import random


a1 = random.randint(0, 100)
a2 = random.randint(0, 100)

b1 = random.randint(0, 100)
b2 = random.randint(0, 100)


if a1 > b1 and a1 > b2:
    with open("result.txt", "w") as f:
        f.write("Win")
elif a1 == b1 or a1 == b2 or a2 == b1 or a2 == b2:
    with open("result.txt", "w") as f:
        f.write("Unkown")
    # print("Unkown")
elif a2 > b1 and a2 > b2:
    with open("result.txt", "w") as f:
        f.write("Win")
elif a1 < b1 and a1 < b2:
    with open("result.txt", "w") as f:
        f.write("Lose")
elif a2 < b1 and a2 < b2:
    with open("result.txt", "w") as f:
        f.write("Lose")
```

если что эта ошибка которая выдает проверяющая система соревнования по программированию

Comment: В коде нет реализации логики `когда любой из игроков команды A гарантированно одержит победу над любым игроком команды B` и наоборот. Если используете проверяющую систему, то нужно выводить именно то, что ожидается, и туда, куда нужно

Comment: СРОЧНО нужно бежать на фриланс, СРОЧНО, там вам помогут, причем ОЧЕНЬ СРОЧНО

Comment: логика как раз есть, это система соревнования ошибку выдает

Comment: `логика как раз есть`  - хорошо, покажите, как победа первой команды определяется. Я вижу, что первый иф этого не гарантирует, и второй елиф ещё хуже.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Задача говорит, что ввод надо задать **вручную**.
   Значит вместо

   ```
   import random


   a1 = random.randint(0, 100)
   a2 = random.randint(0, 100)

   b1 = random.randint(0, 100)
   b2 = random.randint(0, 100)
   ```

   применитe например

   ```
   a1, a2 = input().split()
   b1, b2 = input().split()

   a1, a2, b1, b2 = int(a1), int(a2), int(b1), int(b2)
   ```
2. Подобно для вывода — не в файл, а **на экран**.
   Значит, вместо пары команд типа

   ```
   with open("result.txt", "w") as f:
       f.write("Win")
   ```

   применитe просто

   ```
   print("WIN")
   ```

   (все буквы прописные, т.е. не `"Win"`).
3. Для гарантированной победы нужно чтобы **любой** игрок одной команды победил **любого** игрока второй команды, т.е. например недостаточно

   ```
   if a1 > b1 and a1 > b2:
       print("WIN")
   ```

   Должно быть вычислены все 4 пары:

   ```
   if a1 > b1 and a1 > b2 and a2 > b1 and a2 > b2:
       print("WIN")
   ```
4. В ветвлении (`if`-`elif`-`else`) обработайте сначала выигрыш первой команды, затем второй, а в ветви `else` уже автоматически остается результат UNKNOWN:

   ```
   if a1 > b1 and a1 > b2 and a2 > b1 and a2 > b2:
       print("WIN")
   elif a1 < b1 and a1 < b2 and a2 < b1 and a2 < b2:
       print("LOSE")
   else:
       print("UNKNOWN")
   ```